# Как импортировать RestrictChatMember Aiogram

Tags: python, telegram-bot, aiogram

```
from aiogram.methods.restrict_chat_member import RestrictChatMember
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'aiogram.methods'
```

Из [документации](https://docs.aiogram.dev/en/dev-3.x/api/methods/restrict_chat_member.html#method-as-object), использовал обе формы иморта, на каждый раз выпадает одна и та же ошибка

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ну так вы открыли доку для 3 версии, а у вас скорее всего 2.

```
# хз почему он лежит в вебхуке
from aiogram.dispatcher.webhook import RestrictChatMember
```

На всякий случай оставлю импорт для 3.

```
from aiogram.methods import RestrictChatMember
```